# JLabel: using HTML and method call together

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

When using `JLabel`, is there a way to use HTML and method call together?

For example:

```
        JLabel speedLabel = new JLabel("<html><b>Speed: </b></html>" + plane.getSpeed());
```

This doesn't work.
It only shows `Speed:` and ignores the rest.

Comment: `"<html><b>Speed: </b></html>" + plane.getSpeed()"` There is no good reason to use HTML here. `new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, 16)` would do just as well (better, given you now have direct control over the size of the font on a per pixel basis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your code to this:

```
JLabel speedLabel = new JLabel("<html><b>Speed: " + plane.getSpeed() + " </b></html>");
```

The text, or in your case the airplane speed, that is probably a double, must be in between the `<html>` and `</html>` tags, to be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

it is discarding the values after html close tag if you something like this it will work `JLabel speedLabel = new JLabel("<html><b>Speed: " + plane.getSpeed() + "</b></html>");`